# How to concat multiple columns in a data frame using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying concat multiple columns in a data frame . My column list are present in a variable. I am trying to pass that variable into concat function but not able to do that.

Ex: base_tbl_columns contain list of columns and I am using below code to select all the columns mentioned in the varibale .

```
    scala> val base_tbl_columns  = scd_table_keys_df.first().getString(5).split(",")
    base_tbl_columns: Array[String] = Array(acct_nbr, account_sk_id, zip_code, primary_state, eff_start_date, eff_end_date, load_tm, hash_key, eff_flag)

val hist_sk_df_ld = hist_sk_df.select(base_tbl_columns.head,base_tbl_columns.tail: _*)
```

Similarly, I have one more list whcih I want to use for concatenation. But there the concat function is not taking the .head and .tail argument.

```
scala> val hash_key_cols = scd_table_keys_df.first().getString(4)
    hash_key_cols: String = primary_state,zip_code

 Here I am hard coding the value primary_state and zip_code.
    .withColumn("hash_key_col",concat($"primary_state",$"zip_code"))

 Here I am passing the variable hash_key_cols .
   .withColumn("hash_key_col",concat(hash_key_cols ))
```

I was able t do this in python by using the code below.

```
hist_sk_df = hist_tbl_df.join(broadcast(hist_tbl_lkp_df) ,primary_key_col,'inner' ).withColumn("eff_start_date",lit(load_dt))**.withColumn('hash_key_col',F.concat(*hash_key_cols))**.withColumn("hash_key",hash_udf('hash_key_col')).withColumn("eff_end_date",lit(eff_close_dt)).withColumn("load_tm",lit(load_tm)).withColumn("eff_flag",lit(eff_flag_curr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
val base_tbl_columns: Array[String] = ???

df.select(concat(base_tbl_columns.map(c => col(c)): _*))
```

or:

```
df.select(expr(s"""concat(${base_tbl_columns.mkstring(",")})"""))
```

Comment: It's worked for me. Iused the first option. scala> val hash_key_cols = scd_table_keys_df.first().getString(4).split(",")
hash_key_cols: Array[String] = Array(primary_state, zip_code)
val hist_sk_df = hist_tbl_df.join(broadcast(hist_tbl_lkp_df) ,Seq(primary_key_col),"inner" ).withColumn("eff_start_date",lit(load_dt)).withColumn("hash_key_col",concat(hash_key_cols.map(c => col(c)): _*))

Comment: Want to use similar varibale in join also scala> primary_key_col
res59: String = acct_nbr
scala> delta_primary_key_col
res60: String = delta_acct_n   . I want to use this two variable in my join key... How can it be done.         val cdc_new_acct_df = delta_src_rename_df.join(hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df ,(delta_src_rename_df($delta_primary_key_col) == hist_tgt_tbl_Y_df($primary_key_col),"left_outer" ))

Comment: anyone have this in python?